# sed unterminated `s' command

Tags: centos, sed

I'm getting:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 46: unterminated `s' command
```

On this code:

```
sed -i.bak -c 's|net.ipv4.ip_forward.*|net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1|' /etc/sysctl.conf
```

My editor is showing that char 46 is between the .* special characters.

I'm working on centos 5 to 6.5 machines.

Changing the delimiter didn't help nor did using " instead of ' and the code seems to work on linux mint 17.3's terminal, minus the -c. I think it might be interpreting the . or the * not as a special character.

I tried :

```
sed 's/net.ipv4.ip_forward.*/net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1/' /etc/sysctl.conf
```

It took 10 minutes and did nothing so I stopped it. Works on mint 17.3.

Comment: `sed(1)` has no (standard) option `-c`...

Comment: That commands works perfectly on my CentOS 6.7 machine.  I can't reproduce this problem...

Comment: @Sato The man page on the server said that there was a -c option. Would explain why mint didn't have it though.

Comment: Does it work on CentOS without the `-c`? What does the `-c` do according to your server's man page? Does it work if you use the standard `/` delimiter?

Comment: @terdon If I remove -c I get the same error. 

-c, --copy

              use  copy  instead of rename when shuffling files in -i
              mode (avoids change of input file ownership)

Comment: Ah, right. In general  it is best to post the simplest command that reproduces the error, to avoid confusion. So, if you still get the error with `sed 's/net.ipv4.ip_forward.*/net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1/' /etc/sysctl.conf`, please [edit] your question to show that command. If you *don't* get the error with that, then edit to tell us :)

Comment: Can not reproduce this error with BSD nor with GNU `sed`, with pipes as delimiters or otherwise. Also, "`char 46`" refers to position 46 *within the `sed` script*, i.e. between `=` and `1`.  Hmm... I wonder why?

Comment: Start up a new `bash` session with `env -i bash --noprofile --norc` and try again. If that works, then there's something wonky in your ordinary shell environment.

Comment: BTW, what shell *are* you using on that machine? And what `sed`?

Comment: Thanks everyone I was able to find the solution because of your comments!

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that my editor was being stupid and I thought it was word wrapping.

When I put

```
sed -i.bak -c 's|net.ipv4.ip_forward.*|net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1|' /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Into the editor the "/etc/sysctl.conf" would be touching the edge of the window so it displayed part of it on the next line. I thought it was just word wrapping but nope. Centos or nano decided that "/etc/sysctl.conf" should be put onto a new line if I uploaded the file or copied the code into it. I manually deleted the new line and it works normally.

Edit: Whenever I am using nano and type a / while text is approaching the end of the window it decides to put it on a new line, werid. It acts like it's word wrapping but instead it just breaks everything.

That new line doesn't exist where I'm uploading it from.

[image: Fuuuuuuuuuuu]

Comment: Very interesting.  Perhaps you should use Vim?  ;)